# qsub is executing my bash script in csh despite shebang

Tags: bash, csh, qsub, shebang, sungridengine

I want to submit a bash script to my university's Sungrid computing cluster to run an executable in a loop. When I log in to the server, I'm in bash:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

And I include a bash shebang at the top of the script that I pass to qsub:

```
$ cat shell_sub
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N bSS_s13
#$ -o logs/bSS_s13.log
#$ -j y
#$ -cwd

echo $SHELL > shell.txt
```

But when I submit the above script:

```
qsub shell_sub
```

It instead executes in csh:

```
$ cat shell.txt
/bin/csh
```

How can I force qsub to execute my script with bash instead of csh?

Comment: What is the shell type you get on the cluster? (echo $SHELL)

Comment: @Finch_Powers It says `csh`... so my entire post is an XY problem. I'll edit to focus on the actual issue.

Comment: Try explicitly executing bash:  bash -c "echo $SHELL"

Comment: Call "bash" on the remote machine to gain access to that shell and then it your script should work.

Comment: @Steve I was hoping to use bash constructs like for loops within the body of my script. With your approach I'd need to write two scripts, one to call bash and set qsub variables, and the other to execute my code. I'd prefer a single-file solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the shell for a submitted job (at least in Torque) using [-S](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-1-0/adminGuide/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm#-S).

For example: `qsub shell_sub -S /bin/bash`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your queue is configured with `shell_start_mode` as `posix_compliant` and the defined `shell` is listed as `/bin/csh` (which is the default). To check this:

```
$ qconf -sq <name-of-queue> | grep shell
shell                 /bin/bash
shell_start_mode      unix_behavior
```

If you don't know the name of your queue, it's probably `all.q`.

- If `shell_start_mode` is `posix_compliant`, then the shebang line is ignored and the job (if it's not submitted as binary: `-b y`) is started with the shell defined by the `shell` setting.

  - Why? From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sge_queue_conf): "POSIX does not consider first script line comments such a ‘#!/bin/csh’ as being significant. The  POSIX standard  for  batch queuing systems (P1003.2d) therefore requires a compliant queuing system to ignore such lines but to use user specified or configured  default  command  interpreters  instead."
- If `shell_start_mode` is `unix_behavior`, then the shebang line is used to determine the shell for the job.

You can ask your administrator to consider changing the queue settings.

Comment: Output is `shell                 /bin/csh
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant`, so you've solved the mystery of *why* this was happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but a different order worked for me:

qsub -S /bin/bash shell_sub

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34656977)